Forms Authentication alongside Microsoft Identity
I have an existing ASP.NET MVC app which uses forms authentication (basic username/password), and I want to add the ability to sign in using Microsoft Identity. The trouble I am having is that when I include this in the startup:
 app.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(factory);

the user gets taken straight to the Microsoft site automatically, and doesn't have the option to choose which sign in method they want.
Can anyone advise on how to prevent this from happening?
What I need is for the user to continue to see the existing forms based login screen, and only be taken to the Microsoft authentication site if they choose to do so.
Full OWIN configuration below:
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12|SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/UserAccount/Login")
});

app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

OwinTokenAcquirerFactory factory = TokenAcquirerFactory.GetDefaultInstance<OwinTokenAcquirerFactory>();

app.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(factory);
factory.Build();



Also in web.config I have this setting:
<authentication mode="None">

Thanks

Please post your full ConfigureServices method - or whatever approach you're using to configure OWIN + etc.
